# clone a fork project in bitbucket

Tags: fork, clone, bitbucket, git-bash

I am new to bitbucket. I am reading bitbucket documentation to learn it. I am at the fork concept. In fork documentation they provide a tutorial how to clone fork repository to my local machine. The tutorial is using the TortoiseHG Workbench. I have forked the external repo to my repo. Now I want to clone my fork repository using git bash because I already clone a git repo. I am unable to clone a fork repo using bit bash. Is fork repo only cloned using TortoiseHG Workbench or there is also a command  for cloning.

I am using these commands for cloning my fork repo.

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:user/myqoute.git
```

the error is

```
conq: not a git repository.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to fork (meaning make a clone on the BitBucket side) a *Git* repository, not a mercurial one like [tutorials/tutorials.bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/tutorials/tutorials.bitbucket.org).

Use for instance [tutorials/online-edit-starter](https://bitbucket.org/tutorials/online-edit-starter).

Then you can clone that fork with:

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/yourUserName/online-edit-starter.git
```

(using yours BitBucket credentials: username and passwords)

Or:

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:yourUserName/online-edit-starter.git
```

(provided you registered your public ssh key in that repo)

---

***How to clone Repository ?*** ([proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17117555) by [Rajesh Chaubey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4269738/rajesh-chaubey))

First take of fork repository:

```
 git clone https://rajeshchaubey87@bitbucket.org/rajeshchaubey87/uispark.git
```

(copy your repository url.)
(then go to your master folder).

```
cd uispark
git remote add upstream https://animatorstar@bitbucket.org/animatorstar/uispark.git
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
git remote -v
git status
git add -A
git commit -m "your comment here"
```